# android download http video file

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

I have a very simple program http downloading program as following. The file is very small, like 200K.

The problem is that when I use 3G connection, sometimes one download will be stucked for a very long time. But I can watch youtube very well with 3G connection which means the 3G network is good. Is there anything wrong with the code?

There is no problem when I use wifi connection.

```
for (int chunkno = 0; chunkno < 10000000; ++chunkno)
{
try
{
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://ipaddress/vbr_100.mp4");   
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    recvbytes = response.getEntity().getContentLength();

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("bill"), "f");
    if (!f.exists())
    {
        f.createNewFile();
    }

    response.getEntity().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(f));

}
catch (IOException ex)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Your not doing the same thing as Youtube though, you are downloading the entire file, whereas the Youtube client gets a smaller portion of the video, in chunks, and displays it. Aka, it streams the data, which your not doing.

Comment: I mean is it possible to avoid the stuck by changing the code here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use android [DownloadManager package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), which takes care of all issues related to huge files download.

Copied from the Android document site: 
`The download manager is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots.` 
A very good example of using `DownloadManager` is provided [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-downloadmanager-example.html).

Hope this helps !!